# Ruby on rails. Controller params pre-processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller in ruby on rails 4 and i need to pre-process its params during request processing.

I receive parameters:

```
{"_json"=>[{"date"=>"9/15/2014", "name"="James"},{"date"=>"2/11/2014","name"=>"John"}]}
```

And i need to iterate through all json array elements and update name parameter by adding 'User' post fix. So, finally my json should be:

```
[{"date"=>"9/15/2014", "name"="James **User**"},{"date"=>"2/11/2014","name"=>"John **User**"}]
```

How can i do it in my controller?

Comment: You can used `before_filter` and placed your logic in particular method for modifying your params

Comment: Can you help me with this logic? I am new in ruby

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, you can use this method to return and transform params values: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.2.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-transform_values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
params = {"_json"=>[{"date"=>"9/15/2014", "name"=>"James"},{"date"=>"2/11/2014","name"=>"John"}]}
```

Then modify params using using

```
params["json"].each { |h| h["name"] = "#{h['name']} **User**" }
puts params["_json"]
```

if you want to preprocess for each action then used `before_filter`

Comment: thx! and can i replace date string by real date to pass it in my model using this way?

Comment: you can replace date same way as name.